# Trying to display a views list with order based upon current node being viewed

Tags: views

I have a view block which shows lists of content type "news" which displays in a sidebar showing only the node title for users to peruse.

There are about 150 such "news" nodes and so I use pagitation.

These "news" nodes are completely linear. You always want to read them in order. So if you read node/20, you must read node/21 next, then node/22 etc.

I would like the view block in the sidebar to display the titles of 2 nodes BEFORE and AFTER the current node. So, if I went to node/20, I would like the view block to display:

- Title of node/18
- Title of node/19
- Title of node/20 (current node being viewed)
- Title of node/21
- Title of node/22

I was hoping for some pointers as to how I might achieve this. All things that I've tried thus far have proved futile.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your View, under Block Display, go to:

**Advanced-> Contextual filters (Add)->Content: NID**

In the "When the filter value is NOT available" option select:

**Provide default value-> PHP Code**

and add the following code:

```
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
  $nodeid = arg(1);
  $result = strval($nodeid-2) . "+" . strval($nodeid-1) . "+" . strval($nodeid) . "+" . strval($nodeid+1) . "+" . strval($nodeid+2);
  return $result;
}
```

Last but not least, under "More", select the option: **"Allow multiple values"**

Comment: You can get the node id from URL "Provide default value-> Content ID from URL" and use it as $handler->argument in validation code under: "When the filter value IS available or a default is provided", so it can be made without the IF statement. My +1 for an example of using PHP code in contextual filter.

Answer (score 1):

In relation to your comment:

**Limit the output of this view to a particular content type**

```
$nid = $handler->argument;  // the node id from url
$nodes = array();           // an array for node id's
$type = "news";             // content type (mashine name)

// get two previous node id's and the present one
$result = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} 
                    WHERE nid <= :nid 
                    AND status = :status 
                    AND type = :type 
                    ORDER BY nid DESC 
                    Limit 3", 
                    array(  ":nid" => $nid, 
                            ":status" => 1, 
                            ":type" => $type
                            )
                    );
foreach ($result as $row){
    $nodes[] = $row->nid;
}

// get next two node id's
$result = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} 
                    WHERE nid > :nid 
                    AND status = :status  
                    AND type = :type 
                    ORDER BY nid ASC 
                    Limit 2", 
                    array(  ":nid" => $nid, 
                            ":status" => 1, 
                            ":type" => $type
                            )
                    );
foreach ($result as $row){
    $nodes[] = $row->nid;
}

// compose and return the filter argument
$handler->argument = implode('+',$nodes);
return $argument;
```

***"Allow multiple values" has to be selected***

This solution should suit your needs if your are going to show this block only on particular content type ("news" in this case).

Comment: Thank you for your input here. Having thought about this some more, I think that I really DO need to think about the deleted nodes. There might well be many of those.

Not being a programmer, I'd really appreciate your input on how I might limit the output of this view to a particular content type. Would you just do this in the Views UI, or would you add code to the above?

If it's adding code, what might I need to add please?

Thanks again.

Comment: I edited my answer and wrote the code which limit the output to a particular content type. I think, in this case it should be done with the php code. Just replace the previous code for the new one.